# How can I put a favicon on a computer-based webpage?

Tags: html, favicon

My web page is not actually live on the internet. I have it saved on my computer and I am simply opening the HTML file from my computer- the navigation of the website is all on my computer. Anyway, before I put my site live on the internet, I want to test out all my code, including my favicon. My favicon is not showing up, though. Here is the code I found to be most recommended so far:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: You'd have to specify a full path to the favicon, as it's not likely to be in your computer's root directory

Comment: If you're not running a web server and you're just opening the file from your hard drive, make sure the favicon is in the same folder/directory as your HTML file (not in a subfolder/subdirectory) and remove the / in front of favicon.ico in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try "shortcut icon" instead of "icon":

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And note that the path to your favicon is relative to the html file. If both are in the same directory, the path is just "favicon.ico", no slash.

Comment: I tried it without the slash before. It didn't change anything

Comment: And adding chortcut didn't change anything, either.

Comment: index.html and favicon.ico in the same directory?

Comment: shortcut instead of chortcut

Comment: Please test this, does the favicon show up? <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Answer (score 0):

favicon.ico must be in your root folder, same place where is your index.html, and of course you must have a localhost server

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link` element is correct as such (though the `type` attribute is redundant, and all that it could achieve is to *prevent* a browser from using the icon), but the URL `/favicon.ico` is relative and generally does not work when the HTML document is local. A locally accessed HTML document has a `file:` URL, and such URLs are by definition system-dependent, and in practice they also depend on the browser, too. For example, in a typical Windows system, in you placed favicon.ico directly in the root of the C: disk (requiring normally admin privileges for that), Chrome would find it, Firefox wouldn’t, as they use different `file:` URLs when you open local files.

So in local testing, you should normally use relative URLs that are relative to the current document, e.g. as in `href=favicon.ico` (when favicon.ico is in the same folder as the referring HTML file) or as in `href=../images/favicon.ico` (when favicon.ico is in an `images` folder that is a sibling of the folder where the referring HTML file lies).

If you need to test locally with URLs that relative to the server root, you should download and install a local HTTP server, such as XAMPP.